# What is the jQuery equivalent of mootools Array.include()?

Tags: jquery, arrays, include, mootools

I'm trying to add an element to an array only if it doesn't already exist in the array.  I used to do this with the [Array.include](http://mootools.net/docs/Native/Array#Array:include) method of mootools, but now I'm using jquery.

Is there a method to do this in jquery?

http://mootools.net/docs/Native/Array#Array:include

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I found it...

[jQuery.unique();](http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.unique#array)

http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.unique#array

Answer (score 0):

Removing my stupid answer...

As a general rule, I recommend using [jQuery Documentation](http://docs.jquery.com) and [jQuery API browser](http://api.jquery.com)

Comment: Oops, sorry about this one, answered too fast